# Provisional headers are shown only for my ip address

Tags: php, http, ip-address, http-request

Whenever I send HTTP Post Request to upload files through an HTML form, it hangs on my ip address. I've done a lot of troubleshooting.

- very simple HTML form,
- only the form is in the PHP file,
- submit the form to itself,
- i tested across multiple browsers,
- i spoof my ip addresses,
- discussed with my web hosting tech support,
- my htaccess doesn't have any information on it,
- my php.ini is blank, but i'm on a sharing plan
- my ip address is static, but other static ip address worked
- tried it on multiple computers

I've narrowed it down and the ONLY factor is that my ip address has to changed in order for my form to work, and, any other internet or ip address I use works. Just not mine.

This is the only lead (error) I was able to get (from my browser). The request payload hangs and I get a "Provisional headers are shown" response. Which means I never get a response from the server.

I don't know what else to do...

```
Request URL:(my website)/test

Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhu1ciw7TVToAFrks
Origin:(my website)
Referer:(my website)/test/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryhu1ciw7TVToAFrks
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryhu1ciw7TVToAFrks
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test2"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryhu1ciw7TVToAFrks
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="030ed76cba3b52b9e62fab1d0899d430"

391a64e997010b24845071ec5274421c
------WebKitFormBoundaryhu1ciw7TVToAFrks
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WP55T3S7XJS2"

7H5W8K53HX
------WebKitFormBoundaryhu1ciw7TVToAFrks--
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I figured out that it was related to my wireless connection. I don't know why or what was going wrong, but it was solved after I disabled and enabled the wifi again.

Comment: i'm assuming you mean turning on and off your router when you say disable and enable. which probably gave you a new ip address. I have a static ip address. so it won't help.